# How to aggregate OHLC 5 min from 1 min nested array data (mongodb, mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb data storage with 1 minute OHLCV data like below (time, open, high, low, close, volume) stored using mongoose in nodejs.

```
{
   "_id":1,
   "__v":0,
   "data":[
      [
         1516597690510,
         885000,
         885000,
         885000,
         885000,
         121.2982
      ],
      [
         1516597739868,
         885000,
         885000,
         885000,
         885000,
         121.2982
      ]
      ...
   ]
}
```

I need to extract in same format for 5 minute interval from this data. I could not find how to do that in mongodb/mongoose, even after several hours of searching as am newbie. Kindly help. It is confusing esp because its nested array, and not having fields inside array.

**NOTE**: Suppose for 5 min data, you will have 4 samples(arrays) of 1 min data from data base, then 
time : time element of last 1 min data array (of that 5 min interval)
open : first element of first 1 min data array (of that 5 min interval)
high : max of 2nd element in all 1 min data arrays (of that 5 min interval)
low : min of 3rd element in all 1 min data arrays (of that 5 min interval)
close : last of 4th element in all 1 min data arrays (of that 5 min interval)
volume : last element of last array in all 1 min data arrays (of that 5 min interval)
Please check the visual representation [here](http://i.cubeupload.com/34jHaX.png)

Idea is to be able to extract 5 min, 10 min, 30 min, 1 hour, 4 hours, 1 day intervals also in the same manner from the base 1 min database.

Comment: Try a package like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ohlc-aggregator

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregate pipeline for doing this comparing the first element in data array which is stored in epoch time, get the epoch time of your `$start` and `$end` interval, use that value in query

```
 db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$project : {
            data : {
                    $filter : {input : "$data", as : "d", cond : {$and : [{$lt : [ {$arrayElemAt : ["$$d" , 0]}, "$end"]}, {$gte : [ {$arrayElemAt : ["$$d" , 0]}, "$start"]}]}}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

Comment: It did not return anything. Besides please check the NOTE section I added in the question.

Comment: have you changed the `$start` and `$end` values in the query, it should be epoch time in number? and data for that period exists in collection?

Comment: I did but still empty result. yes data exists in collection.. Here is the query I executed. 

`db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$project : {
            data : {
                    $filter : {input : "$data", as : "d", cond : {$and : [{$lt : [ {$arrayElemAt : ["$$d" , 0]}, "1516599860285"]}, {$gte : [ {$arrayElemAt : ["$$d" , 0]}, "1516597690510"]}]}}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()`

Comment: Please find sample dataset here
https://gist.github.com/parthi2929/36e6898cff7be45ccdd008ec750e70e9

Comment: Did. Again nothing returned.

Comment: Also where do you extract OHLC in your query?

Comment: I did with the test data in question, have you changed the collection name to your collection name in the query?

Comment: yes I did. stack overflow is asking to move to chat but i dont have enough reputation. any way we could chat?

Comment: Please check visual representation of what is needed [here](http://i.cubeupload.com/34jHaX.png)

Comment: Stack overflow is asking to go to chat as our discussion is lengthy. Anyway we could chat? Please help.